# Mongo DB Backup & restore

Tags: mongodb

0 down vote favorite

I have a DB with 150GB of data. I am using the MongoDump and Mongorestore methods to backup and restore.

My production server is running Mongo 2.2 and my test server is 2.6.1

When I take a back up from the Mongo2.2 production server it's taking a long time to complete. The restoration take 6-8 Hours. It hasn't completed without error. Sometimes the restore is dropped automatically and we need to run the restore again or restore the missed collection.

Is there a better way to to take a backup and restore method, where we can save time and run it without Errors?

Regards,

Rishi

Comment: First, I'd like to advice you that it is a Very Bad Idea™ To have different versions of any component in test and production. You should downgrade your test environment. Having different versions running on test and production leads to the dreaded "Works on our test environment" type of bugs. Second, please elaborate which boxes those instances run on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply markus. We are running these instance with Amazon EC2 . Production is running on RHEL and QE is running on Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1):

With a single node i don't think you have other option than mongodump and LVM snapshot. In the case you run on a replica set which is recommended for production you can just stop one secondary and copy the data directory.

Comment: I'd like to add that LVM is not a poor mans solution. If done right, it is reliable, easy to script and reasonably fast.

Comment: Agree and have use them in the past, the 1 node configuration is poor design for a production.